# Where is the logic located which determines the tpl file for the front page?

Tags: theming

We are using Drupal 6. When accessing `http://www.mysite.com/`, the tpl file which is displayed is named `page-front_page.tpl.php`. I cannot figure out where the logic is which decides that `page-front_page.tpl.php` will be used for the front page.

I created a second file, named `page-front.tpl.php`, and this will display instead of `page-front_page.tpl.php`, seemingly bypassing `page-front_page.tpl.php`.

Does anybody know how `page-front_page.tpl.php` is defined as a front page? Or is there some sort of automatic URL parsing happening here?

**Edit 1.0:** Please read my comments to answers below for more information.

Comment: Not sure if it applies to Drupal 6 but this Stackoverflow post shows other places where theme suggestions could be specified: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194109/drupal-7-candidate-page-tpl-name-for-particular-custom-content-type-entry

Comment: @nmc - Thanks, but it doesn't seem to apply to 6

Answer (score 3):

please review in /includes/theme.inc near to the line `if (drupal_is_front_page()) {`...

```
if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
    $suggestions[] = 'custom-page-front-name-here';
  }
```

I changed the `$suggestions[]` value, and I saw that .tpl.php name to the front page can be customized.

According the comment of nmc,

> this file/code should not be modified as it is part of Drupal core

. this is only to locate where can be stablished the value.

Comment: In my `theme.inc` file, the line is `$suggestions[] = 'page-front';`, and that still doesn't explain why `page-front_page.tpl.php` is being used. Thank-you though!

Comment: Just to clarify, while the file naming convention may be set in `includes/theme.inc` in the code that moon.watcher has posted but this file/code should **not** be modified as it is part of Drupal core.  See http://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core for more details on why not to hack core.

Comment: hello nmc, yes, the question is where can be the value. and I agree about that can not be used this way.

Comment: Hi letseatfood, review if $suggestions was overwrited in another place of theme.inc, so review more declarations using $suggestions

Comment: @moon.watcher - Yeah, I looked for that, but there is not an override.

Comment: @letseatfood, search the value **page-front_page** inside files (for example `grep -R "page-front_page" files` ) or inside site's database.

Comment: @moon.watcher - did that :-)

Comment: @moon.watcher - I haven't dug through the db yet.

Answer (score 2):

If the URL for the page that you set as front page is example.com/front_page, then one of the suggestions used by Drupal is "page-front_page"; this causes Drupal to look for "page-front_page.tpl.php."

The code that selects that suggestion is in [template_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6):

```
  // Build a list of suggested template files in order of specificity. One
  // suggestion is made for every element of the current path, though
  // numeric elements are not carried to subsequent suggestions. For example,
  // http://www.example.com/node/1/edit would result in the following
  // suggestions:
  //
  // page-node-edit.tpl.php
  // page-node-1.tpl.php
  // page-node.tpl.php
  // page.tpl.php
  $i = 0;
  $suggestion = 'page';
  $suggestions = array();
  while ($arg = arg($i++)) {
    $arg = str_replace(array("/", "\\", "\0"), '', $arg);
    $suggestions[] = $suggestion . '-' . $arg;
    if (!is_numeric($arg)) {
      $suggestion .= '-' . $arg;
    }
  }
  if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
    $suggestions[] = 'page-front';
  }
```

For example.com/front_page, `arg(0)` returns "front_page" and the suggestion will be "page-front_page."

That suggestion comes before "page-front"; that means that in the case there is a file named "page-front_page.tpl.php" it will be used instead of "page-front.tpl.php."

Comment: If both "page-front.tpl.php" and "page-front_page.tpl.php" are present, and `http://example.com/front_page` is accessed, then "page-front.tpl.php" is displayed. If "page-front.tpl.php" does not exist, and `http://example.com/front_page` is accessed, then "page-front_page.tpl.php is displayed. So, I gather that page-front.tpl.php has priority. But, if "page-front.tpl.php" is not present and I rename "page-front_page.tpl.php" to something like "page-front_example.tpl.php", then access `http://example.com/front_example`, a "Page Not Found" is displayed.